# Weighted-random probability in Java

Tags: java, probability

I have a list of fitness values (percentages), which are ordered in descending order:

```
List<Double> fitnesses = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

I would like to choose one of these Doubles, with an extreme likelyhood of it being the first one, then decreasing likelyhood for each item, until the final one is close to 0% chance of it being the final item in the list.

How do I go about achieving this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Sorry, but this question hardly makes any sense.  We can answer how to randomly pick an element from a list using a probability function.  However, your question also talks about "exponential difference", "list of percentages", and "descending order", which all seem like [red herrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). You might want to reword your question to make it clearer what it is that you have and what it is that you want to get.

Comment: Ok, I've updated it to be less speculative. I hope this is clearer, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Karl that's my problem really, I am aware there are lots of useful libraries and functions out there, I'm unsure what to look for. Thanks for the list, but it's rather overwhelming - do you have anything in particular there you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select "one of these Doubles, with an extreme likelihood of it being the first one, then decreasing likelihood for each item, until the final one is close to 0% chance of it being the final item in the list" then it seems like you want an exponential probability function. (**p = x<sup>2</sup>**).

However, you will only know whether you have chosen the right function once you have coded a solution and tried it, and if it does not suit your needs then you will need to choose some other probability function, like a sinusoidal (**p = sin( x * PI/2 )**) or an inverse ratio (**p = 1/x**).

So, the important thing is to code an algorithm for selecting an item based on a probability function, so that you can then try any probability function you like.

So, here is one way to do it.

Note the following:

1. I am seeding the random number generator with 10 in order to always produce the same results.  Remove the seeding to get different results at each run.
2. I am using a list of `Integer` for your "percentages" in order to avoid confusion.  Feel free to replace with a list of `Double` once you have understood how things work.
3. I am providing a few sample probability functions.  Try them to see what distributions they yield.

Have fun!

```
import java.util.*;

public final class Scratch3
{
    private Scratch3()
    {
    }

    interface ProbabilityFunction<T>
    {
        double getProbability( double x );
    }

    private static double exponential2( double x )
    {
        assert x >= 0.0 && x <= 1.0;
        return StrictMath.pow( x, 2 );
    }

    private static double exponential3( double x )
    {
        assert x >= 0.0 && x <= 1.0;
        return StrictMath.pow( x, 3 );
    }

    private static double inverse( double x )
    {
        assert x >= 0.0 && x <= 1.0;
        return 1/x;
    }

    private static double identity( double x )
    {
        assert x >= 0.0 && x <= 1.0;
        return x;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( { "UnsecureRandomNumberGeneration", "ConstantNamingConvention" } )
    private static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random( 10 );

    private static <T> T select( List<T> values, ProbabilityFunction<T> probabilityFunction )
    {
        double x = randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
        double p = probabilityFunction.getProbability( x );
        int i = (int)( p * values.size() );
        return values.get( i );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList( 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 );
        Map<Integer,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        for( int i = 0;  i < 10000;  i++ )
        {
            int value = select( values, Scratch3::exponential3 );
            counts.merge( value, 1, ( a, b ) -> a + b );
        }
        for( int value : values )
            System.out.println( value + ": " + counts.get( value ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: @KenReid glad to be of help!  C-:=

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it that gives you the ability to approximate an arbitrary weight distribution.

The array passed to WeightedIndexPicker indicates the number of "buckets" (>0) that should be allocated to each index. In your case these would be descending, but they don't have to be. When you need an index, pick a random number between 0 and the total number of buckets and return the index associated with that bucket.

I've used an int weight array as it's easier to visualize and it avoids rounding errors associated with floating point.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class WeightedIndexPicker
{   
    private int total;
    private int[] counts;
    private Random rand;

    public WeightedIndexPicker(int[] weights)
    {
        rand = new Random();

        counts = weights.clone();       
        for(int i=1; i<counts.length; i++)
        {
            counts[i] += counts[i-1];
        }
        total = counts[counts.length-1];
    }

    public int nextIndex()
    {
        int idx = 0;
        int pick = rand.nextInt(total);
        while(pick >= counts[idx]) idx++;
        return idx;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] dist = {1000, 100, 10, 1};

        WeightedIndexPicker wip = new WeightedIndexPicker(dist);        
        int idx = wip.nextIndex();

        System.out.println(idx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all this code to answer your question since your question seems to be much more about math than code. For example, using the apache commons maths library getting a distribution is easy:

```
ExponentialDistribution dist = new ExponentialDistribution(1);
// getting a sample (aka index into the list) is easy
dist.sample();
// lot's of extra code to display the distribution.
int NUM_BUCKETS = 100;
int NUM_SAMPLES = 1000000;

DoubleStream.of(dist.sample(NUM_SAMPLES))
    .map(s->((long)s*NUM_BUCKETS)/NUM_BUCKETS)
    .boxed()
    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), TreeMap::new, counting()))
    .forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k.longValue() + " -> " + v));
```

However, as you said, there are *so many* possible distributions in the math library. If you are writing code for a specific purpose then the end user will probably want you to explain why you chose a specific distribution and why you set the parameters for that distribution the way you did. That's a math question and should be asked in the mathematics forum.